# How I make a dmg installer that will automatically open after download?

Tags: macos, dmg

I have seen some dmg's which not only mounts after download but also copies the installer in the download folder and open the installer in Installer Application.

I don't know how to do it?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DropDMG works great for me:
http://c-command.com/dropdmg/

I don't know how to achieve this otherwise (free alternative / manually).

Answer (score 8):

I haven't seen automatically opening dmg files, but it's possible to make folder open automatically after user mounts the dmg file.

Once you have created the [dmg file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96882/how-do-i-create-a-nice-looking-dmg-for-mac-os-x-using-command-line-tools), mount it and then issue following command:

bless --folder /Volumes/NAME --openfolder /Volumes/DIRECTORY

The NAME is your the mounted folder name and DIRECTORY is the directory that you wish to open automatically, often NAME and DIRECTORY are the same.

Comment: As of 10.7.5 this doesn't work: Authorization required.

Answer (score 7):

the `--folder` option is not necessary if just want the dmg to open the finder folder window automatically once mounted

```
bless /Volumes/NAME --openfolder /Volumes/DIRECTORY
```

The `NAME` is the mounted folder name and `DIRECTORY` is the directory that you wish to open automatically, often `NAME` and `DIRECTORY` are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Script that will do this for you:

https://github.com/andreyvit/create-dmg

Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
test -f Application-Installer.dmg && rm Application-Installer.dmg
create-dmg \
--volname "Application Installer" \
--volicon "application\_icon.icns" \
--background "installer\_background.png" \
--window-pos 200 120 \
--window-size 800 400 \
--icon-size 100 \
--icon "Application.app" 200 190 \
--hide-extension "Application.app" \
--app-drop-link 600 185 \
"Application-Installer.dmg" \
"source_folder/"
```