# How do I create a nice-looking DMG for Mac OS X with a localized background?

Tags: macos, localization, dmg, diskimage

I have read the discussion on [how to create a DMG for Mac OS X using command-line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96882/how-do-i-create-a-nice-looking-dmg-for-mac-os-x-using-command-line-tools) and now I would like to go further: can I possibly produce a DMG which displays a different background image, based on the active language of the system?

I know there are tricks to display different folder names based on the active locale; but can this be extended to different backgrounds? It would be a pity to have to produce and distribute one DMG for every language our product supports, just to have a different background image.

Here are two background images I would like to use, in English:

[image: Install Crésus (English version)]

or in French:

[image: Install Crésus (French version)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if the situation has changed, but I do know that as of a few years ago it, it was exceedingly difficult to create a localized DMG; I think it meant having to produce a DMG for each supported language (obviously cumbersome for highly-localized projects). I worked on a few open-source projects that had this same concern. I think the general consensus was to design a background that showed how to copy the application *graphically*, rather than using words. This is the approach taken by big open-source Mac projects like Adium and Firefox.

Comment: Indeed. We decided to go graphical too.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using DropDMG for app distribution:
http://c-command.com/dropdmg/

Don't reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: I'll have to give it a try. Thanks for the tip.