# Create dmg installer for mac

Tags: macos, applescript

I need to build dmg installer of a mac app. I heard that can make it through apple script. 
Can anybody help how this can be done easily. Also I am not aware of Apple Script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do at least one web search on 'Create dmg installer for mac' before asking a question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `hdiutil` command for creating dmg.

> hdiutil uses the DiskImages framework to manipulate disk images. 
>   Common
>        verbs include attach, detach, verify, create, convert, compact, and burn.

```
hdiutil create -ov -srcfolder source applicationName.dmg
```

Take a look at [How do I create a nice-looking DMG for Mac OS X using command-line tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96882/how-do-i-create-a-nice-looking-dmg-for-mac-os-x-using-command-line-tools)

Comment: Hi, I have did this yesterday. Actually what I want was to make package of Mac application. While googling I found about Apple's Package Maker tool. But I am confused about the scripts to be used with it. Do we need to write any scripts to get the look of wizard. I need to give different sections in the installer, like license, system authentication(not sure), etc. Then the installation should proceed step by step. How this can be done?