# How to include an alias to applications when using macdeployqt

Tags: qt, alias, macdeployqt

I'm trying to find a way to include an alias to the applications folder with my application. I'm trying to get it to look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Excuse me if I misunderstand you, but macdeployqt is a command line tool used to set the Qt library paths in an OSX application binary. What has that got to do with the alias to the Applications folder in a disk image?

Comment: Well, the image you see here shows the what chromecast setup does. It's a .dmg file but it includes an alias to your applications folder to make it easy to drag and drop the application to your applications folder.

Comment: I understand that, but  you state that you want to do this "preferably using macdeployqt if possible" and the two are completely different things.

Comment: I suppose you're right. Post edited.

Comment: I disagree that this has "nothing to do" with macdeployqt, since one of its features is to make the .dmg file using the `-dmg` flag. It's just that this feature lacks the ability to add the /Applications alias, so some other tool will have to be used to make the .dmg if this is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you might want:

http://dmgcreator.sourceforge.net/en/

> ### Features
>
> - Create compressed and internet enabled DMG files, i.e. for software    distribution
> - Add a background image and a custom volume icon to your    disk image
> - Add a symbolic link to the Applications folder for easy    installation
> - Show localized license agreements when mounting the disk    image. They have to be accepted by the user in order to access the
>     contents.
> - Content positioning at a pixel level
> - The disk image's    content will always look the same, irrespective of the user's finder configuration

And another link if you don't like the dmgcreator program.

http://asmaloney.com/2013/07/howto/packaging-a-mac-os-x-application-using-a-dmg/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments to your question, this is nothing to do with `macdeployqt`.

See [How do I create a nice-looking DMG for Mac OS X using command-line tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96882/how-do-i-create-a-nice-looking-dmg-for-mac-os-x-using-command-line-tools)

Also,

- http://digital-sushi.org/entry/how-to-create-a-disk-image-installer-for-apple-mac-os-x/
- http://el-tramo.be/guides/fancy-dmg/