# Set folder background image on Mac with Python

Tags: python, macos

I would like to change the background images of folders in Mac OS 10.9 based on their name. I can't seem to find any way of changing the background picture in Python or much information about the background picture in general.

I believe things such as background image and icon positioning are stored in the .DS_Store, is it a possibility to modify this to change the image?

If it is not possible in Python is there a suggested language to be able to so this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe things such as background image and icon positioning are stored in the .DS_Store, is it a possibility to modify this to change the image?

you can explore the `DS_Store` settings using the `xattr` command, or the `ls -@` command if you're using default osx utils.

> If it is not possible in Python is there a suggested language to be able to so this?

there is the [`xattr`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xattr) python package that lets you do this.

For the background images, I found [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1513578/1290438) though it's mostly about DMGs.

Though, there's a [graphical recipe](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Background-of-a-Folder-in-Mac-Os-X) to actually change a folder's background, I still can't find the extended attribute property being used there…

I did change a folder's background, but there's no extended attributes setting that has been changed because of that. And that folder contains no `.DS_Store` file as well. That information maybe stored in some `Application Support` or `Preferences` database used by the finder…

Finally, you could code your own DS_Store parsing module easily, using the following information:

- https://wiki.mozilla.org/DS_Store_File_Format

which tells us that the DS_Store has indeed a background field.

Finally, it looks like perl has a `DS_Store` module:

- http://www.digininja.org/projects/fdb.php