# Few issues while creating DMG from scripts

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, applescript, dmg

I am able to create a DMG and it installs the app. So far so good.

But the issue I am facing is the scripts (shell and applescripts) creates a window with maximise button enabled. Clicking the maximise button makes the window look ugly, as bottom is cut. Also if you resize the window the background image does not cover the full window and shows white background.

For reference (see the images, as almost all DMG installer has similar issue )

[image]
[image]

What I want is

1. To disable the maximise button.
2. To fix the window size so that it can't be resized by dragging.

Comment: Good question. I'm not aware that either is possible? When I've create custom DMG's I've used AppleScript (to automate the process), my guess is you're doing something similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96882/how-do-i-create-a-nice-looking-dmg-for-mac-os-x-using-command-line-tools.

Comment: Workaround for window resizing? http://joemaller.com/659/setting-icon-position-and-window-size-on-disk-images/

Comment: @petert: Yes similar codes. I tried every thing, googled and lastly I posted the issue. As you can see same issue persist even in Dropbox!!!

Comment: that window is basically Finder, I am pretty sure you can't control.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't control this. This window is a Finder window, not something you "own"; while you can set the default initial view, you can't prevent the user from changing the view -- resizing the window, switching to list, column, or cover flow view, showing the sidebar and toolbar, etc. Basically, the Finder is for browsing files & folders, not for presenting customized UI, and the standard tricks (rigged initial view settings & background image) are about as far as you can fake it.

Comment: I liked ur comment. As im the applescript part we can show/hide toolbar statusbar etc. Thats why I wanted to check if by means we can overridw to make it better.