# How to disable the sheet asking "Do you want to move the installer to the Trash?" after installation is complete

Tags: operating-system, installation, macos-sierra, pkgbuild, productbuild

I use pkgbuild productbuild to build the installer. However, installing on OS X 10.12 Sierra, after installation is complete, I see the sheet "Do you want to move the installer to the Trash? To keep this package and disk image in its current location. click Keep."

I want to disable that sheet. How to do that?

Does anyone have more info about that new behavior?

[image: Do you want to move the installer to the Trash?]

Comment: I have the exact same question.  Sorry to see no one has answered it!

Comment: How did you set the Name of the installer displayed in there? I am having issues because my problem is my message is incomplete.
Do you want to move the "" installer to the Trash?
Basically, the prompt doesn't have my installer name on it.

Comment: Hi @Aaron, you can find out the anwser in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96882/how-do-i-create-a-nice-looking-dmg-for-mac-os-x-using-command-line-tools
The tool hdiutil lets you determine the volume title.