# How can I make my .app to .dmg in Mac OS with some extra hidden files in it

Tags: macos, installation, dmg

I had created a simple music application in Qt platform in Mac OS with Desktop Clang -64bit compiler.I need to deploy my application over other Mac PC as per my requirement, I had converted my .app  which I had got from while releasing my application(I had used macdeployqt to add library files to my application), and converted it to .dmg by using disk utility. My application runs well on the other Mac PC but I need to deploy my style sheet along with my application but I am unable to add style sheet folder to my .dmg file.
I need to add folder along with my .dmg file but I dont know how to do that and what is the right path to keep my folder in other Mac pc.
.
All the possible solution are welcome.
Thanks In Advance.

I did the same process in Window and I used Inno setup compiler to create my .exe setup file and added my style sheet through it. Do we have some similar software to create .dmg in Mac OS

Answer (score 0):

I'm very pleased to use this shell script: [create-dmg](https://github.com/andreyvit/create-dmg) (it is available in homebrew) to include a background image, a license file, icons, that sort of thing. I've not used the options for adding files and folders to the dmg, but it has them. See also [this SO  question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96882/how-do-i-create-a-nice-looking-dmg-for-mac-os-x-using-command-line-tools).